# solutions of $p = 2q + r$

Tags: prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

let $P$ denote the rational primes of the for $4k+3$, and let $Q$ denote the set containing $1$ and all the rational primes of form $4k+1$. let $p \in P$. we look for representations of $p$ of the form
$$
p = 2q + r
$$
where $q,r \in Q$. for example:
$$
3 = 2 \cdot 1 + 1 \\
7 = 2 \cdot 1 + 5\\
11 = 2 \cdot 5 + 1 \\
19 = 2 \cdot 1 +  17 \\
23 = 2 \cdot 5 + 13 \\
31 = 2 \cdot 1 + 29 \\
43 = 2 \cdot 1 + 43 \\
47 = 2 \cdot 17 + 13 \\
59 = 2 \cdot 29 + 1 \\
67 = 2 \cdot 13 +  41 \\
71 = 2 \cdot 5 + 61 \\
79 = 2 \cdot 13 + 53 \\
83 = 2 \cdot 41 + 1 \\
103 = 2 \cdot 1 + 101 \\
107 = 2 \cdot 5 + 97 \\
127 = 2 \cdot 13 + 101 \\
131 = 2 \cdot 17 +97 \\
139 = 2 \cdot 19 +101 \\
151 = 2 \cdot 61 + 29 \\
163 = 2 \cdot 61 + 43 \\
167 = 2 \cdot 29 + 109 \\
179 = 2 \cdot 53 + 73 \\
$$
**question** are these examples atypical, or are such representations fairly common, as appears from these first few values of $p$? i have no programming facilities at the moment, so, my curiosity having been caught, i would be grateful if someone could provide a reference to some relevant study and/or some estimates of the frequency with which a solution exists as $p$ increases in  size.

Comment: And the title made it seem so easy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is conjectured that every odd number (greater $7$) can be written as $2q + r$ for odd primes $r,q$. This is called [Lemoine's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemoine%27s_conjecture) sometimes also Levy's conjecture and  should be about as difficult as Goldbach's conjecture.

This is not exactly your question as you have an additional congruence condition; however there are variants of the Goldbach conjecture that also impose additional congruence conditions.

In any case, standard heuristics would predict that all but finitely many odd number congruent $3$ modulo $4$ can be written as $2q+r$ for primes congruent $1$ modulo $4$. To prove it might be somewhat harder than Goldbach's conjecture.

Comment: thank you for the reference.